Laravel route with parameter. The first letter of the parameter changes only for one word
I have been testing route functionality of laravel, and I come across a problem which has no meaning at all. This is my route definition below
Route::get('/greet/{name}',function($st_name){
    return 'Good morning ' . $st_name;
})->name('greeting');


Now, the problem is when I call the URL in the address bar it works fine except for my name. When I send my name as the query parameter it goes through the route definition and changes the first letter to capital in the address bar as well as in the return string. I have no idea why it behaves this way, and it happens every time I send my name as the query string.
I have cleared the route cache, and the view cache but they didn't help.

does it do it for all browsers?

I was testing on the MS Edge, and I have just checked it on Chrome, and it seems it happens only on the Edge browser. I am just curious to find out why it behaves as such.

Chromium based browsers seem to be misbehaving for me lately with very aggressive history recalling. Try clearing your history and checking again

You can use this code.
Route::get('/greet/{name}',function(string $st_name){
    return 'Good morning ' . $st_name;
})->name('greeting');

enter image description here
